# Variable en bash de ubuntu que contenga la fecha en la que se creó la variable de forma automática?

Tags: ubuntu

necesito ayuda para crear una variable en ubuntu la cual contenga la fecha en la que se ha creado esa variable de forma automatica...

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con automática? ¿Solo quieres obtener la fecha y hora actual?

Comment: mira por favor [ask].. Podes ser mas claro con la pregunta? que intentas hacer?

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza la notación de fecha y hora con el comando date:

```
dt=$(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'); #variable
echo "$dt" #imprimes aqui
```

> [Manual sobre dateformat en linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html)